# Pandas multiindex group by index value different from X

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe.

```
                             balance
id            currency              
3             1WO       1.732174
              ADH       7.734906
              ALX       3.854667
              AMLT      4.308590
              ANCT      1.259457
...                              ...
646902        BTC       2.000000
              ETH       1.495225
676329        BCH       0.000000
              BTC       0.000000
              ETH       3.022524
```

I would like to group by `id` not in 3 & `currency` and sum the balances.
In addition the new grouped id gathering several id would be called 29.
I could do the following but it miss the additional condition of gathering index data not in `3` and rename it:

```
groupby(['currency','app_vendor_id']).sum()
```

Any contribution would be appreciated.

Edit:

expected output:

```
                             balance
id            currency              
3             1WO       1.732174
              ADH       7.734906
              ALX       3.854667
              AMLT      4.308590
              ANCT      1.259457
...                              ...
29            BTC       2.000000
              ETH       4.517869
```

Comment: i dont really understand what you mean. so you want all ids exept 3 and groupby currency?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: I have updated to show what i wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `rename` by all values without `3` in first level:

```
ids = df.index.levels[0]
d = dict.fromkeys(ids[ids != 3], 29)
df1 = df.rename(d, level=0)
print (df1)
              balance
id currency          
3  1WO       1.732174
   ADH       7.734906
   ALX       3.854667
   AMLT      4.308590
   ANCT      1.259457
29 BTC       2.000000
   ETH       1.495225
   BCH       0.000000
   BTC       0.000000
   ETH       3.022524
```

And then use `sum`:

```
print (df1.sum(level=0))
      balance
id           
3   18.889794
29   6.517749

print (df1.sum(level=1))
           balance
currency          
1WO       1.732174
ADH       7.734906
ALX       3.854667
AMLT      4.308590
ANCT      1.259457
BTC       2.000000
ETH       4.517749
BCH       0.000000

print (df1.sum(level=[0,1]))
              balance
id currency          
3  1WO       1.732174
   ADH       7.734906
   ALX       3.854667
   AMLT      4.308590
   ANCT      1.259457
29 BTC       2.000000
   ETH       4.517749
   BCH       0.000000
```